# Set focus after window hide in GXT

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, gxt

I have such issue - for example, when I'm clicking on grid cell - there appears gxt window(gxt popup, gxt dialog, etc.  Not native browser/OS dialogs). After window usage, when it  became hidden - grid losts its focus. How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: can't you simply re-focus as soon as the popup closes? Also if you show some code we can follow more closely what's (not) happening.

Comment: Grid and Popup don't know about each other.

Answer (score 1):

So I've just added method

```
protected native Element getActiveElement() /*-{
    return $wnd.document.activeElement;
}-*/;
```

which saves current active element in private field `Element savedElement`, into overriden `Window.onLoad()`. Then I just call `savedElement.focus()` from that element in `Window.onHide()`. That's all.